# Topology generated $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ is order topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I want to prove the following things.

Consider the real line $\mathbb{R}$. Now take the metric $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ to make it a metric space. Now I want to prove the topology generated by $d$ is order topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

I noticed that for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $(a,b) = B_d(\frac{a+b}{2}, \frac{b-a}{2})$.

But I have no further ideas. How should I prove this?

Comment: Do you know a base or a subbase for the order topology on $\Bbb{R}$?  Can you recite one?  Are the elements of that base or subbase elements of the topology induced by the metric $d$?

Comment: **Hint:** Given $x,y,r$, we have $d(x,y)<r$ if and only if $x-r<y<x+r.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order topology has as its standard base all open intervals, which you can see as open metric balls.

The metric topology has as its standard base all open balls, which are open intervals too.

So both the metric and the order define the same base, hence the same topology. C’est tout.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your answer. I have understood the following things from your answer...  Tthe basis of order topology on $X$ is collection of sets of the form 1. $(a,b)$ if there is no smallest and largest element, 2. $[a_0,b)$ if $a_0$ is the smallest element and 3. $(a,b_0]$ if $b_0$ is the largest element. Here $X  = \mathbb{R}$, hence it has no smallest and largest element, so only basis element is of the form $(a,b)$. Previously, I noticed  that $(a,b) = B_d(\frac{a+b}{2}, \frac{b-a}{2})$ and also every $\epsilon$-ball $B_d(x, \epsilon) = (x - \epsilon, x+\epsilon)$, hence open.

Comment: Hence, the metric topology and order topology define the same base so they are equal. Am I right?

Comment: @user454229 yes, that’s also how I end my argument.